# errors when PHP include is run twice

Tags: php, include

I have an include on my site that provides a link to narrow a database request for each starting letter, when it is run once on the site it runs fine.  However, I would like to include it both at the top and bottom of the page and this seems to cause a problem as it shows each link twice.

Below is the code in the include

```
<?php
$alphas = range('A', 'Z');
$url =  'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

foreach ($alphas as $letter) {
    $elements[] = "<a href=$url?firstletter=$letter>$letter</a>";
}
echo implode(', ', $elements);
```

I have tried checking whether $alphas exists and only running $alphas = range('A', 'Z') if it doesn't but that didn't help.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Initialise `$elements` before the `foreach` i.e. `$elements = array();` or `$elements = [];`

Comment: @RiggsFolly still runs unnecessary loop twice

Comment: You did  init before the loop like this right? `$elements = array(); foreach ($alphas as $letter) { ...`

Comment: @nogad Why did you delete your answer

Answer (score 2):

Just test in the first line of the code if the `$elements` arrays already exist. Then the second time the code runs, it just explodes the `$elements` array that was created at the top of the script. No extra variables required!

```
<?php
if ( ! isset($elements) ) {
    $alphas = range('A', 'Z');
    $url =  'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $elements = array();
    foreach ($alphas as $letter) {
        $elements[] = "<a href=$url?firstletter=$letter>$letter</a>";
    }
}
echo implode(', ', $elements);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used to solve the issue, not saying it's the best, just what I used.

```
<?php
if (!isset($elements)) {
$alphas = range('A', 'Z');
$url =  'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

foreach ($alphas as $letter) {
    $elements[] = "<a href=$url?firstletter=$letter>$letter</a>";
}
echo implode(', ', $elements);}
else {
    echo implode(', ', $elements);
}
```